# Alternator Upgrade: Sizing cable to battery

Tags: electrical, alternator

I am trying to figure out the size of wire I need to get for my new, 160 amp, alternator.  I found this chart which shows the resistivity/length of different wire gauges.  Chances are that I will not be using 160 amps but I want to make sure that my wiring is adequate in case I ever draw a large amount of current. If I need 4 feet of wire between my alternator and battery what size would be the safest?

Also, what is the difference between chassis wiring and "power transmission"?

[image]
(source): http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm

Answer (score 6):

This is actually much simpler than that chart implies. Don't worry about ohms per thousand feet - for a four foot length this will be very very low. What is more important is the maximum current a wire is rated to.

So here the question is whether you will want the OO gauge as it is rated to 190A in the power transmission column, or the 2 gauge as it is rated to 181A in the chassis wiring column.

**Update** - a quick bit of research, that also agrees with Mike's answer: The chassis wiring column is the relevant one, so go for the 2 gauge.

Not 100% sure exactly what they mean by chassis and power categories in this context, to be honest.

Comment: I don't know either but it's copied from the site that was linked.

Comment: Yeah, I think that chassis wiring is when it is grounded to the chassis and there is only a positive cable.

Comment: @SpongeBob, the ground won't make a difference as it won't change the current in the wire. I *suspect* that the difference is that in a "power transmission" application a (more) continuous load is expected and thus more sustained heating of the wire. Ampacity ratings are often based on the insulation of the wire and its ability to withstand heat.

Answer (score 3):

I use [this](http://www.the12volt.com/info/recwirsz.asp) guide. For 160amps you probably want at least a 2 gauge (as seen in power&ground cable specs) but you could probably get away with a 4 gauge run if it is short.